# Software for managing multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have two monitors. I'm looking for software that performs the following:

- Press a key combination (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) and the active window is moved and resized such that it takes up all available space on the left-hand monitor
- Press a key combination (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) and the active window is moved and resized such that it takes up all available space on the right-hand monitor

The software must be free.

**EDIT**
I'm using Windows XP.

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5845/are-tool-requests-on-topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Windows 7, you can use The Windows Key and the Arrow Keys to do this. Win-L and Win-R to move the window, Win-Up to maximize it.

If not, check out [DisplayFusion](http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/), or Autohotkey.

Comment: DisplayFusion works nicely

Answer (score 2):

As Phoshi mentioned, you could do this with [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) if you don't have Windows 7. In fact, someone has already [made a similar script](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic21703.html) for managing windows on multiple monitors called WindowPad!

> **WindowPad**
>
> Use a pad concept to arrange windows.
>   Use the Numpad or your own custom
>   layout to move and resize a window to
>   fill the appropriate section of the
>   screen.
>
> Though the concept is based on HiRes
>   Screen Splitter by JOnGliko, I wrote
>   WindowPad from scratch to add some
>   features. Those features are:
>
> - Multiple-monitor support. It should work with any number of monitors in
>     any setup.
> - Unresizable windows are positioned correctly.
> - Windows that aren't supposed to be resizable (i.e. calc) are not resized.

here are the current hotkeys:

```
; WindowPad:
;
;   Move and resize windows with Win+Numpad.
;     Win+Numpad1 = Fill bottom-left quarter of screen
;     Win+Numpad2 = Fill bottom half of screen
;     etc.
;
;   Move windows across monitors. For example:
;     Win+Numpad4 places the window on the left half of the screen.
;     Win+Numpad4 again moves it to the monitor to the right.
;
;   Quick monitor switch:
;     Win+Numpad5 places the window in the center of the screen.
;     Win+Numpad5 again moves the window to the next monitor.
;     (This works by monitor number, not necessarily left to right.)
;
;   QUICKER Monitor Switch:
;     Win+NumpadDot switches to the next monitor (1->2->3->1 etc.)
;     Win+NumpadDiv moves ALL windows to monitor 2.
;     Win+NumpadMult moves ALL windows to monitor 1.
;
;   Other shortcuts:
;     Win+Numpad0 toggles maximize.
;     Insert (or some other key) can be used in place of "Win".
```

Of course, you can modify the code to your liking.

Answer (score -1):

The best software out there for this IMO is [Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/).

**EDIT:** Sorry, just read it has to be free.