# How do I manage multiple monitors in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

My Acer TM5720 used to run on Vista. The ATI utility worked perfectly to manage multiple monitors. (I have an external display to the left of the laptop. The external should be the primary display and the laptop screen the secondary. When I remove the external display, everything moves back to the laptop display automatically. Connect the external display and it becomes the primary display again.)

Now I'm running Windows 7 and there are no official ATI drivers available. I am using the Windows display driver for my screen card (ATI Mobility Radeon X1700). Windows allows me to easily set up my display arrangement, however when I disconnect the external display, the laptop screen does not become the primary display and all windows open on the external display becomes inaccessible.

Is there any (free) software out there that can give me back the functionality I had before?

Comment: @Michael, what are you pointing out? That link points to this page.

Comment: I meant this one http://superuser.com/questions/97832/software-for-managing-multiple-monitors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key Windows + P should solve your problem.

Comment: Great tip, sure is easier than going through menus and confirmations as I'm doing at present.

It is still not perfect though, as when you disconnect the external display, you have to remember the number of key presses required to get the primary display back to the laptop.

Am I wishing for too much?

Comment: Use the key before disconnecting the other monitor.